API reference section blank on readthedocs
I am trying to get documentation on the readthedocs for my package epspy (https://github.com/shikharmittal04/epspy.git). I can see all the sections on the documentation except for the API reference section, which is completely blank. Note that when I am working on my local PC I can see the API generated successfully.
I have only one module called meps.py in src/epspy
I followed the solution on https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/1139
I added the following set of code in my conf.py
def run_apidoc(_):
    from sphinx.ext.apidoc import main
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
    cur_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    module = os.path.join(cur_dir,"..","src/epspy")
    main(['-e', '-o', cur_dir, module, '--force'])

def setup(app):
    app.connect('builder-inited', run_apidoc)

However, the API section is still blank.

What does the build log on RTD say?

Actually, it should have been module = os.path.join(cur_dir,"..","src/epspy") instead of module = os.path.join(cur_dir,"..","meps"). However, the API section is still blank.
